# xml filtering with python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I have a following xml document:

```
<node0>
    <node1>
      <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
      <node2 a1="x2"> ... </node2>
      <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
    </node1>
</node0>
```

I want to filter out `node2` when `a1="x2"`. The user provides the xpath and attribute values that need to tested and filtered out. I looked at some solutions  in python like BeautifulSoup but they are too complicated and dont preserve the case of text. I want to keep the document same as before with some stuff filtered out.

Can you recommend a simple and succinct solution? This should not be too complicated from the looks of it. The actual xml document is not as simple as above but idea is the same.

Comment: Your XML document is not well formed. It is missing some "/" characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This uses `xml.etree.ElementTree` which is in the standard library:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xee
data='''\
<node1>
  <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
  <node2 a1="x2"> ... </node2>
  <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
</node1>
'''
doc=xee.fromstring(data)

for tag in doc.findall('node2'):
    if tag.attrib['a1']=='x2':
        doc.remove(tag)
print(xee.tostring(doc))
# <node1>
#   <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
#   <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
# </node1>
```

This uses `lxml`, which is not in the standard library, but has [a more powerful syntax](http://codespeak.net/lxml/index.html):

```
import lxml.etree
data='''\
<node1>
  <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
  <node2 a1="x2"> ... </node2>
  <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
</node1>
'''
doc = lxml.etree.XML(data)
e=doc.find('node2/[@a1="x2"]')
doc.remove(e)
print(lxml.etree.tostring(doc))

# <node1>
#   <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
#   <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
# </node1>
```

**Edit:** If `node2` is buried more deeply in the xml, then you can iterate through all the tags, check each parent tag to see if the `node2` element is one of its children, and the remove it if so:

Using only xml.etree.ElementTree:

```
doc=xee.fromstring(data)
for parent in doc.getiterator():
    for child in parent.findall('node2'):
        if child.attrib['a1']=='x2':
            parent.remove(child)
```

Using lxml:

```
doc = lxml.etree.XML(data)
for parent in doc.iter('*'):
    child=parent.find('node2/[@a1="x2"]')
    if child is not None:
        parent.remove(child)
```

Comment: I realized this does not work when node2 is further nested inside. I can find the tag using doc.findAll('node1/node2'), but I cannot remove it from doc. Any suggestions?

Comment: @saminny, I've added some code showing how to deal with this situation.

Comment: Nah, Python is just an eminently useful language. If choosing to use it makes me a genius, then you must be a genius too! :)

Comment: Could you please introduce a good tutorial about elementTree, I have to do some filtering on my xml files but i am confused about the difference between elem, tag and attribute. I have to remove some blocks and tags from my xml.

Comment: @OrclUser: For a quick overview of XML which will explain the difference between elements and attributes, see [DiveIntoPython Chapter 12](http://www.diveintopython3.net/xml.html). For a tutorial on Python's standard lib xml.etree, see [Doug Hellman's Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html). And for more on `lxml.etree`, see the [lxml.etree tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html). For a quick introduction to XPath, you might start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp), and [here for reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).