# Python and XML : How to filter xml elements based on attribute value

Tags: python, xml

I am very new to python.

I have an xml file with data like this:

```
<SCHEDULE type="ILN_BGY_G162_SL1D2T4T4SL2D2T4T4" inter_league="0" balanced_games="1" games_per_team="162" preferred_start_day="2">
    <GAMES>
        <GAME day="-34" time="1905" away="14" home="9" type="2" />
        <GAME day="-34" time="1905" away="16" home="11" type="2" />
        <GAME day="78" time="1905" away="12" home="15" type="2" />
        <GAME day="79" time="1905" away="6" home="8" type="2" />
    </GAMES>
</SCHEDULE>
```

I am trying to remove all elements of the xml file that have a `day` value NOT in the list `day_range` where `day_range = [78,79,80]`.  With the sample data above, I would remove the elements where day="-34" and retain those where day="78" and day="79".

I have followed the answers in the following questions very closely and have gotten various errors and unwanted results that I will explain below.  Accepted solutions I have tried:

[XML Filtering with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869564/xml-filtering-with-python)

[How do I Filter Values From XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286633/how-do-i-filter-values-from-xml-file-in-python)

When I try the following code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

day_range = [78,79,80]

schedule = ET.parse(path)
root = schedule.getroot()
for element in root:
    for day in element:
        if element['day'] in day_range:
           root.remove(element)
```

I get a Type error on `if element['day'] in day_range:` element indices must be integers.

Changing it slightly as below, I get a ValueError on `root.remove(element)`: list.remove(x): x not in list

```
for element in root:
    for day in element.findall('GAME'):
        if element[0] in day_range:
            root.remove(element)
schedule.write('test.xml')
```

I would like the output xml to look like this:

```
<SCHEDULE type="ILN_BGY_G162_SL1D2T4T4SL2D2T4T4" inter_league="0" balanced_games="1" games_per_team="162" preferred_start_day="2">
    <GAMES>
        <GAME day="78" time="1905" away="12" home="15" type="2" />
        <GAME day="79" time="1905" away="6" home="8" type="2" />
    </GAMES>
</SCHEDULE>
```

I have been working on this all day and I believe that I am missing an important concept but can't quite find it.

Comment: Please edit your question to, first, fix your xml because it's invalid; second clarify if you want to remove days in `day_range` or those NOT on the list; add a couple of example of elements to be removed and a couple of elements to retain, and finally, show your expected output based on these examples.

Comment: edited based on @JackFleeting's comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<SCHEDULE type="ILN_BGY_G162_SL1D2T4T4SL2D2T4T4" inter_league="0" balanced_games="1" games_per_team="162" preferred_start_day="2">
    <GAMES>
        <GAME day="-34" time="1905" away="14" home="9" type="2" />
        <GAME day="-34" time="1905" away="16" home="11" type="2" />
        <GAME day="78" time="1905" away="12" home="15" type="2" />
        <GAME day="79" time="1905" away="6" home="8" type="2" />
    </GAMES>
</SCHEDULE>'''

day_range = {78,79,80}

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
games = root.find('.//GAMES')
for g in games.findall('./GAME'):
    if int(g.attrib['day']) not in day_range:
        games.remove(g)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<SCHEDULE balanced_games="1" games_per_team="162" inter_league="0" preferred_start_day="2" type="ILN_BGY_G162_SL1D2T4T4SL2D2T4T4">
    <GAMES>
        <GAME away="12" day="78" home="15" time="1905" type="2" />
        <GAME away="6" day="79" home="8" time="1905" type="2" />
    </GAMES>
</SCHEDULE
```